# In Ruby on Rails can a scaffold field name contain more than one word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

In Ruby on Rails, if I want to use the scaffold generator, can I use a field name with more than 1 word i.e

```
'class name':text
```

As opposed to just

```
name:text
```

I have tried looking and also tried but cannot figure out if this is possible.

---

Additionally, if I want to generate a scaffold which would be called Class, I appear to be unable to do this - but I would like my users to see the word 'class' rather than whatever new name I am going to have to pick. Anyway around this?

Comment: It's going to become a method on the model, you ever seen a method name with a space in it? follow the conventions and use an underscore, aside from being easier, it won't cause potential problems later on.

Comment: no...but i am a little unsure how the field will become a method? What would a method of name possibly do?

Comment: Huh? Field in the db maps to a property on an instance of the model as in mymodel.mycolumn

Comment: While what you want is possible (except spaces in a name method name). The answer to all your questions, is don't. Rails and active record rely on you complying with the conventions. The underlying code expects that you have done that. If you don't, some bits will break down, and anyone who takes your code on is going call you a non-conventional name.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that even a method with a space in its name is possible (mind the `:"symbol with quotes"` syntax). But calling it will be tricky. So don't do this. Use underscores. (oops, already mentioned below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
rails g migration Foo "bar baz":string

rake db:migrate # => SyntaxError
```

Oops. That generates a migration like this:

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.string :bar baz

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Obviously that won't work. You can fix it by wrapping the symbol in quotes:

```
t.string :"bar baz"
```

Now the migration works, but can we use the model?

```
> f = Foo.new
> f.bar baz # nope
> f."bar baz" # nope
> f.send("bar baz") # Yay!
```

How to change the value?

```
> f.send("bar baz=", "wtf") # OK
> f.send("bar baz") # => "wtf"
```

So in a very narrow, technical sense, yes you can do this. But you shouldn't.

> I would like my users to see the word 'class' rather than whatever new
>   name I am going to have to pick

You can always use a different method (i.e., an alias) for user-facing code to display a column or model name. This can be as simple as defining your own method on a model, or using a helper function, or a decorator class. You definitely want to avoid using terms that Ruby and Rails use (like Class).

Comment: I tend to use `i18n` for UI texts, even if there's only one language.